# Flutter - widget variables are always null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter app connected to firebase, and I'm using it to receive push notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging, using this code. Whenever I call the variables `widget.title`, `widget.body`, they are null, but when the method receives a notification, they have the value that came from FCM. What should I do?

```
class PushList extends StatefulWidget {
  
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> notific;
  String title, body;

  Future<dynamic> fcmMessageReceiver() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((value) {
      if (value != null) {}
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      if (message.notification != null) {
        notificacao = {
          'title': message.notification.title,
          'body': message.notification.body
        };
        title = message.notification.title;
        body = message.notification.body;

        print('MENSAGEM: $notific');
      }
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {});
  }

  PushList() {
  }

  @override
  _PushListState createState() => _PushListState();
}

class _PushListState extends State<PushList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: null,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          widget.notific != null
              ? Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  elevation: 4,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      widget.title,
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      widget.body,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  child: Text("U don't have new notifcs."),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`PushList` should be immutable. Define the properties inside the state and call `fcmMessageReceiver` inside `initState`. Also you need to call `setState` to trigger rebuild after you set `title` and `body`:

```
class PushList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PushListState createState() => _PushListState();
}

class _PushListState extends State<PushList> {
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> notific;
  String title, body;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fcmMessageReceiver();
  }

  Future<dynamic> fcmMessageReceiver() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((value) {
      if (value != null) {}
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      if (message.notification != null) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            notificacao = {
              'title': message.notification.title,
              'body': message.notification.body
            };
            title = message.notification.title;
            body = message.notification.body;
          });
        }
        print('MENSAGEM: $notific');
      }
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: null,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          notific != null
              ? Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  elevation: 4,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      title ?? '',
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      body ?? '',
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  child: Text("U don't have new notifcs."),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How am I going to call this method? Because it needs to be an initState, and the State class is marked as private. It would be something like this: `PushList().createState().fcmMessageReceiver();`

Comment: Why do you need to call from a parent widget? In flutter this is not how you are suppose to use widgets. You don't keep reference to the widget and call stuff. 

But if you really want to go that way do the folowing:

1. rename `_PushListState` to `PushListState`
2. from the parent widget create global key `final key = new GlobalKey<PushListState>();`
3. pass it to the `PushList(key: key),`
4 . call method from parent: `key.currentState.fcmMessageReceiver();`

Comment: The PushList class is not my main class. If the firebase method is not called in an initState, it will not receive notifications.